# A time line from article of the Wikipedia

Tags: mediawiki-api

I need to make a timeline of a Wikipedia article, the article in question is https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_incerteza_de_Heisenberg. The intention is to visualize the development of the entire page, not just the changes in the text. I need to understand development as a timeline for a material object.

Some help?

Comment: Could you please be more specific in what you are trying to achieve and what you already tried to get a result. A few lines of code that you already tested would be helpful. If you do not have any code yet it would be good if you simply draw a draft of what you expect and add it to your question.

Comment: 0

I do not have any code, sorry :'( .

I am trying to visually see the development of the page from its creation to its current state. In this case, it would be https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Princ%C3%ADpio_da_incerteza_de_Heisenberg&oldid=148618

until: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_incerteza_de_Heisenberg

But visually. How the article appears to the reader. It would be a timeline of the page, so that we can visually track all the edits made to the article.

I tried to use https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/#/Page%20content

Comment: and what happened when you tried to use that? what was the result, and why was that wrong or insufficient? again, at _least_ an illustration of what you want to see is needed.

Comment: Sorry for my inability in use this forum.

I think tha I found what i need: https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-api-demos/blob/master/python/get_pages_revisions.py

I will try this. And move on as I can...

Thanks.

Comment: Please get back to your question when you run into detail problems with your approach. As far as I understand you'd like to create sort of a GIF-Movie of the changes of a page and animate this. This would be a multiple step process. You need the wikipage markup of each revsion then render it as HTML including the links to picture and get a graphical representation of that HTML. Please note that the step HTML->graphical representation needs a browser simulation so you might want to look into something like selenium.

Comment: Frankly you sound way in over your head. A look at [existing tools](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benutzer:Atlasowa/edit_history_visualization) might give you a better idea of what you are after and the complexity of the task.